# problem by integration of apache nutch (release 1.2) in apach solr (trunk) - got solr exception

Tags: solr, integration, nutch

I have configured the `solrindex-mapping.xml` (nutch) and configured my solr `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` too. Both working well on single run, but if I use the `bin/nutch solrindex ...` I get an exception:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document [null] missing required field: id
```

I have configured the `id` in all config-files. At `solrindex-mapping.xml` it maps from `url` to `id` and at `schema.xml` of solr I configured the id too. I don't know what's wrong. I add some logging outputs into `org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.java`. I add one loginfo at these line, when the read fields are added to SolrInputDocument. The result after building and running is:

```
2010-09-11 21:31:06,326 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - write()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,327 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: segment, value: 20100911212934
2010-09-11 21:31:06,327 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: boost, value: 1.0
2010-09-11 21:31:06,327 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: digest, value: bc315927b7c01c7a2905d5b6872bc35b
2010-09-11 21:31:06,327 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - close()
```

You will see only 3 read fields O_o. Does anyone know if there is something wrong in my configuration? **I need the running nutch really fast, because I am currently writing on my bachelor thesis :/** (on information integration of heterogenous data sources at the local network)

Best regards
marcel =)

The rest of the log:

```
2010-09-11 21:31:06,079 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - open()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,280 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2010-09-11 21:31:06,280 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: site dest: site
2010-09-11 21:31:06,280 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: metadata_title
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: metadata_last_modified
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: lastModified dest: metadata_last_modified
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: url
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: id
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: id
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: url
2010-09-11 21:31:06,281 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - uniqueKey = id
2010-09-11 21:31:06,291 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - write()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,294 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: segment, value: 20100911212934
2010-09-11 21:31:06,294 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: boost, value: 1.0
2010-09-11 21:31:06,294 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: digest, value: 18abadd34a2bd71a8336fa5e8c6dbedb
2010-09-11 21:31:06,306 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - write()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,306 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: segment, value: 20100911212934
2010-09-11 21:31:06,306 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: boost, value: 1.0
2010-09-11 21:31:06,306 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: digest, value: 3267fd5ea03852cdc83383635d133fad
2010-09-11 21:31:06,310 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - write()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,310 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: segment, value: 20100911212934
2010-09-11 21:31:06,310 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: boost, value: 1.0
2010-09-11 21:31:06,311 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: digest, value: b61607602ab99eda5684adc9966349d6
2010-09-11 21:31:06,314 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - write()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,314 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: segment, value: 20100911212851
2010-09-11 21:31:06,314 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: boost, value: 1.0
2010-09-11 21:31:06,314 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: digest, value: 9bdb8df3d1addf254203542dd22096d3
2010-09-11 21:31:06,316 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - write()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,316 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: segment, value: 20100911212934
2010-09-11 21:31:06,316 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: boost, value: 1.0
2010-09-11 21:31:06,317 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: digest, value: 66eb3639ae15655bf91dc53208f95167
2010-09-11 21:31:06,319 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - write()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,319 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: segment, value: 20100911212934
2010-09-11 21:31:06,319 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: boost, value: 1.0
2010-09-11 21:31:06,319 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: digest, value: 6e0501b52e204c2a68d9caa70dd0dfa9
2010-09-11 21:31:06,326 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - write()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,327 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: segment, value: 20100911212934
2010-09-11 21:31:06,327 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: boost, value: 1.0
2010-09-11 21:31:06,327 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Key: digest, value: bc315927b7c01c7a2905d5b6872bc35b
2010-09-11 21:31:06,327 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - close()
2010-09-11 21:31:06,687 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document [null] missing required field: id
Document [null] missing required field: id
request: http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=1
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:424)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:243)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:49)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.close(SolrWriter.java:98)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)
2010-09-11 21:31:07,556 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

Nutch 1.2 does not work with Solr trunk...

From the Nutch mailing list (original post [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/RESULT-VOTE-Apache-Nutch-1-2-Release-Candidate-4-td1576749.html#a1576749))...

> Do you all know if 1.2 works with current Solr trunk?
>
> It doesn't, it uses Solr 1.4.x. Solr trunk uses incompatible API.